OnPhotonSerializeView() not working on ownership transfer
In Unity3d when i transfer ownership of my photon view,the OnPhotonSerializeView() stops working i tried every option in observables tab of PhotonView
on ownership transfer i want to update position of object based on owner screen position

Could you share your code?
